# Reusing a pipe for several messages

Tags: c, pipe, ipc, unnamed-pipes

I'm writing a code where a parent forks several children, after creating a pipe for each one.
In a while loop, the parent aks the user for some input, and communicates it to a child using a pipe, so the child needs to do some stuff about the input. The problem is that, after the child finishes, the parent process doesn't take control again, so somehow I'm stuck with the child, waiting for another input through the pipe.
I'm really new into this things, so I don't know what I'm doing wrong

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {

  //Création de pipes anonymes (un pour chaque processus)
  int fd[4][2];
  for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    pipe(fd[i]);
  }

  pid_t fils_pid[4];

  //Fork 4 processus fils
  for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    if((fils_pid[i] = fork()) == 0){
 
      close(fd[i][W]); //Ferme les descripteurs d'écriture
      
      while(true){
        read(fd[i][R], query, 100);
        printf("Query: %s", query);
      }
      
      close(fd[i][R]);  
      exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
  }
 
  //children never reach here

  for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    close(fd[i][R]);
  }

  while(true){
    int i = rand() % 4;
    printf("Enter a query: ");
    fgets(query, 100, stdin);

    write(fd[i][W], query, strlen(query) + 1);
    wait(NULL);
    }
  
  close(fd[t][W]);

  printf("Bye bye!\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "child finishes"?  The children are running an infinite loop that never finishes.  What do you mean by "parent process doesn't take control again"?  It's really hard to tell from your descriptions what the problem is and what behavior you want.  Are you saying that the child processes stay alive even after the parent process is terminated, and you want to figure out how to terminate the child processes when parent process is terminated?

Comment: Can you post your *complete* code?  You are missing `#include`s at the top and also the definition of macros like `SELECT`.  This is essential information for anyone trying to help you.  Also, if your code is longer than necessary to demonstrate the problem, it would be good to simplify it down and show a [mcve] (for example, `type` is a set but never used, so it should be removed).

Comment: @DavidGrayson thank you for the advice. I simplified the code, removed some things that were irrelevant to the problem. As for "child finishes" I wanted to say when the child goes through the loop, so the child reads and then prints the information. The program then apparently keeps stuck there, with that same child waiting for the parent to write something else to read it (or at least that's what I figured out that happens). The parent loop never runs again. I hope I explained myself a bit better here

Answer (score 3):

A few issues:

1. The children just `read` forever. They never check for EOF.
2. Parent `wait` in wrong place. Should be at end *after* closing *all* write ends of pipes.
3. Child must close *all* write ends of pipes before starting its loop and *not* just its own.
4. Child must close *all* read ends of pipes *except* its own.
5. Otherwise, each child interferes with a given child seeing EOF on its pipe.
6. Parent never detects EOF and never terminates its loop.
7. Child can *not* rely on receiving an EOS (0x00) terminator in a single `read` because pipes can return *short* reads [or *short* writes].
8. i.e. Child should `fwrite` to `stdout` instead of doing `printf` of received buffer.

---

Here is the refactored code. It is annotated with bugs and fixes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

enum {
    R = 0,
    W = 1
};

char query[100];

int
main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{

    // Création de pipes anonymes (un pour chaque processus)
    int fd[4][2];
    pid_t pid;

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        pipe(fd[i]);
        printf("PIPE %d R=%d W=%d\n",i,fd[i][R],fd[i][W]);
    }

    pid_t fils_pid[4];

    // Fork 4 processus fils
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        if ((fils_pid[i] = fork()) == 0) {
// NOTE/BUG: _each_ child must close _all_ write ends
// NOTE/BUG: _each_ child must close _all_ read ends _except_ its own
#if BUG
            close(fd[i][W]);            // Ferme les descripteurs d'écriture
#else
            for (int j = 0;  j < 4;  ++j) {
                close(fd[j][W]);
                if (j != i)
                    close(fd[j][R]);
            }
#endif

// NOTE/BUG: we can't guarantee an EOS terminator because of pipe short read
// NOTE/BUG: we never stop on EOF
#if BUG
            while (1) {
                read(fd[i][R], query, 100);
                printf("Query: %s", query);
            }
#else
            while (1) {
                ssize_t rlen = read(fd[i][R], query, sizeof(query));
                printf("Query/%d/%zd: ",i,rlen);
                if (rlen <= 0)
                    break;
                fwrite(query,1,rlen,stdout);
            }
#endif

            close(fd[i][R]);
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        }

#if 1
        printf("main: pid[%d]=%d\n",i,fils_pid[i]);
#endif
    }

    // children never reach here
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        printf("main: RCLOSE i=%d\n",i);
        close(fd[i][R]);
    }

    while (1) {
        int i = rand() % 4;

        printf("Enter a query: ");
        fflush(stdout);

// NOTE: bug we don't stop on EOF
#if BUG
        fgets(query, 100, stdin);
#else
        if (fgets(query, sizeof(query), stdin) == NULL) {
            printf("eof ...\n");
            break;
        }
#endif

// NOTE/FIX: stop sending to children if we get a blank line
#if ! BUG
        if (query[0] == '\n') {
            printf("stop ...\n");
            break;
        }
#endif

#if BUG
        write(fd[i][W], query, strlen(query) + 1);
#else
        write(fd[i][W], query, strlen(query));
#endif

#if BUG
        wait(NULL);
#endif
    }

// NOTE/BUG: we should close write ends of _all_ pipes
#if 0
    close(fd[t][W]);
#else
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        printf("main: WCLOSE i=%d\n",i);
        close(fd[i][W]);
    }
#endif

// NOTE/FIX: correct place to wait for children (_after_ closing pipes)
#if ! BUG
    while (1) {
        pid = wait(NULL);
        printf("wait: pid=%d\n",pid);
        if (pid < 0)
            break;
    }
#endif

    printf("Bye bye!\n");

    return 0;
}
```

---

In the above code, I've used `cpp` conditionals to denote old vs. new code:

```
#if 0
// old code
#else
// new code
#endif

#if 1
// new code
#endif
```

I've also used `#if BUG` and `#if ! BUG` for original code and bug fixes.

Note: this can be cleaned up by running the file through `unifdef -k`